# Use regex,How to get below code name and length value?

Tags: java, regex

I have below code:

```
    @Column(name = "SWIFT_NUMBER")
    @Column(name = "SHIP_ADDRESS", length=500)
    @Column(name = "CONTENT",length=10240)
   //@Column(name = "USED_SPACE", columnDefinition = "bigint(20)")
    @Column(name = "TPL", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
```

I want to use java regex to get each line `name` and `length` value

- if current line doesn't with length attribute, only get `name` value
- if current line with `//` java comments, doesn't get name and length 
  value

I try to write regex :

```
.*@Column.*name.*\"(.*?)\"((?:.*)|(.*length.*(\\d+).*))
```

but only get the name value ,can not get the length value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with ruediste that parsing Java code with regular expression is not the best idea, and you should really avoid that (see links above).

However, if you really, really have to, maybe try this regex:

```
(?<!\/\/)@Column.*?name\s*=\s*"(.*?)"(?:.*?length\s*=\s*(\d+))?
```

(First group: name, second group: length, optional)

Comment: sorry,java need escape, i try to use `.*@Column.*?name\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"(?:.*?length\\s*=\\s*(\\d+))?`  but not matches `@Column(name = \"NAME\", length=80)`

Comment: Do you really have `\"NAME\"` in your source? If so, the regex will not match as it allows only whitespaces between `name` and `=` and the quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would load the class and use reflection to read the values. The other approaches would be to use an Annotation Processor (http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/ shows how to generate code. Just use the part reading the information from the parsed classes) or ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/) to read the compiled classes.

Parsing Java Code with regular expressions is generally a messy thing and should be avoided.